# The Legend of Sally the Cow

Tags: visual, computer-puzzle

I was <s>looting</s> exploring Pelagia Farm and I <s>stole</s> found this note <s>in a locked chest</s> on the ground. It seems that one of the farmhands had tried their hand at poetry. I want to know how it ends but some ink bottles next to the note had spilled and obscured the last words. While I look for my next <s>target</s> quest, can you figure out how the poem ended?

[image: Sally the Good Cow]

Comment: f**king dead?..

Comment: Is divine(devine) misspelled intentionally?

Comment: Huh... the wax seal is on the side with the message

Comment: i was half right then

Comment: @AstroMax I'm going to stay in-world here and say that the farmhand must have been a bad speller. It's certainly not that I didn't even spell-check my own work. It's probably due to pronouncing with a hard e sound in my head. I checked, though, and it's *technically* on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/devine). Does that count?

Comment: @WesleySitu The farmhand clearly was writing on the back of some old message they'd receive. Paper can be hard to come by.

Comment: @Engineer Toast haha I would accept that. Thought it could have something to do with the puzzle. No biggie though, I almost misspelled misspelling in my comment.  :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The ending is

> (0x) DEADBEEF
>
>  a common sentinel value in computing as it is a 32bit value that is unlikely to happen by chance.
>  The two color splotches are, roughly, #00DEAD and #00BEEF, confirming this.
>
>  (Actually I got #00deaf and #00bef0 - each slightly higher than expected - but that may be an artifact of compression or something?)

Comment: Nice one! Can't believe I didn't think about checking that. Although final answer may relate more to a common phrase with a similar meaning.

Comment: Well yeah. It's the closest you can get to that in hex hehe

Comment: Heh, did you notice the computer-puzzle tag?

Comment: So, the color-picker was from which editor? :)

Comment: @John GIMP, if you must know

Comment: @Rubio, I don't have to know, but I like Paint.Net as well. Good stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Having made another puzzle somewhat like this, I can confirm that JPG compression does mess the colours up a little. PNG might have been a better choice, but the puzzle is still clearly solvable.

Comment: @ymbirtt This is what I realized as well. It's actually saved as a PNG on my computer but I uploaded it to stack.imgur and it was converted to JPG. I'll have to find a way around that...

Comment: @ Mordechai I had not seen the computer-puzzle tag. Shameful...

Comment: I *did* think of it, within like 10 seconds of reading the puzzle, but was on a mobile device where I couldn't check exactly what the colours were and I didn't want to post something saying "I bet the answer is ..." without being able to say why beyond "it's the obvious thing given the rhyme and the computer-puzzle tag and I bet the colours lead to it somehow". Oh well :-).

Comment: I got a different colour picker, but get DEAF BEF0 too. Close enough I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the end of the poem...

> A thief!

Explanation:

> A rustler is a considered a livestock thief, and the cow just knocked out his teeth. Taking something away from someone ie:(his teeth) can be considered theivery. Also a lot of hints toward theft in the question.

Comment: The puzzle's tags suggest that the image contains hidden information, and that this isn't just wordplay

Comment: @tmpearce Yes as I commented in the question, I had not seen the computer-puzzle tag. Thanks for the heads up though, greatly appreciated.